# Pasting data into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is the same question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546828/python-translation-of-rs-read-table-text-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1), which is marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610889/how-to-copy-paste-dataframe-from-stackoverflow-into-python?noredirect=1&lq=1).
The problem, and the reason I'm still asking, is that the solution provided (using `pandas.read_clipboard()`) currently doesn't work.
I use Python 3.5 and whenever I try to copy data from the clipboard I get an error :

"It seems the kernel died unexpectedly" which [seems to be restricted to 3.5](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#optional-dependencies).

Any other way to get a simple dataframe like the one below in a pandas dataframe without resorting to manually typing it or downgrading Python?

```
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0   1   2   2   1
1   1   3   2   3
2   3   4   4   3
3   4   5   6   5
4   5   6   9   7
```

in `R` I would be using`read.table()` with the `text=` argument

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `io.StringIO` with `pd.read_table`:

```
import io
s = '''
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0   1   2   2   1
1   1   3   2   3
2   3   4   4   3
3   4   5   6   5
4   5   6   9   7
'''

pd.read_table(io.StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True)
Out: 
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0   1   2   2   1
1   1   3   2   3
2   3   4   4   3
3   4   5   6   5
4   5   6   9   7
```

Comment: Couldn't have been better!

Comment: For people using Python 2.7 and get a TypeError, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316333/how-can-i-resolve-typeerror-with-stringio-in-python-2-7