# win32clipboard doesn't exist?

Tags: python, pywin32

I am very new to python, and I just decided today that I would make a program that sets something to my windows clipboard. I searched for a "how-to" and [this link to a stackoverflow site came up.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python)

I proceeded to install pywin32 and try it out for myself. However, once I tried to import win32clipboard, it gave me following error.

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/  and install the version of 'Python for Windows Extensions' appropriate for your version of Python and in consideration of whether you computer is 32- or 64-bit.

Then you can do:

```
import win32clipboard
```