# print numpy array for copy and paste

Tags: python, numpy

Sometimes, I would like to `print` a numpy array just to copy it from the command line into somewhere else. The standard `__repr__` is close, but missing the commas:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(5, 2)
print(a)
```

```
[[0.66585668 0.5793219 ]
 [0.28048686 0.11019737]
 [0.41359919 0.69354774]
 [0.02062253 0.85507001]
 [0.05443759 0.51366551]]
```

Any hints?

Comment: try `print(a.tolist())`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string representation of a numpy array with commas separating its elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423774/string-representation-of-a-numpy-array-with-commas-separating-its-elements) gives `print(repr(a))`

Comment: What about [`np.array2string`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html)?

Comment: Reversing the problem: [Numpy equivalent of pandas.read_clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865437/a-numpy-equivalent-of-pandas-read-clipboard)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your desired output is the following:

```py
[
    [0.5838947919313026, 0.05795999970550392],
    [0.9737053546477267, 0.7160755144818707],
    [0.17361370495727824, 0.09849691691484186], 
    [0.863423476768234, 0.7065666761268419],
    [0.18712559034118503, 0.21525050659592326]
]
```

You can use a list comprehension and the `list` constructor to do this:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5, 2)
print([list(i) for i in a])
```

Comment: This is better achieved with `a.tolist()`.