# How to get currently active window's address bar text

Tags: windows, python-2.7, windows-7

I am trying to get the currently active window's address in the address bar
but there does not seem like there is any module that can do this.

I already looked at pywin32 and it looks like what I am looking for but there isn't any function that retrieves the text in the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

- set file explorer to be currently active window
- send in alt+D keystroke to focus the address bar
- send in ctrl+C keystroke to copy to the windows clipboard
- follow up with [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python) to read in data from the clipboard

and if you're unsure how to simulate keystrokes, there's plenty of googling for that.

good luck!

Comment: yes this would work but wouldn't it overwrite the content of the clipboard? and can the previous content be saved?

Comment: if you want to preserve the clipboard, you can also read from/write to/clear the clipboard using python. i'll let it up to you on how you want to handle that, there's a few ways you can go about it. my suggestion is just a way to accomplish what you're looking for since win32 doesn't have this functionality readily available