# How do I remove spaces/unwanted characters from my PC's clipboard?

Tags: python

I am trying to code something that removes any unwanted characters from my PC's clipboard, example:
a-3-g-6-x to turn into a3g6x, or "H 3 x 8 l" into "H3x8l". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could create a list with all unwanted characters and then iterate over that list and use `replace()` method in your string for each character. But you will have to be more specific in your question.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: How you access the paste buffer depends on your OS. her's an answer for windows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python

Answer (score 0):

you can use `win32clipboard` part of `pywin32`

```
import win32clipboard


# get clipboard data
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

unwanted = [" ", "~"]
data = [s for s in data of s not in unwanted]

# set clipboard data
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()   
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(data)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```