# Getting Clipboard via Python with Ctypes module (in Linux)

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to get *clipboard data* via **python** *ctypes* module for **Linux** . I've searched but i get only for **Windows** solution . This question is a solution but for **Windows** -> [getting clipboard(in windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python).
I found a **Python** module for my situation , module -> [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/)  . But i wondered, could i get the *clipboard data* only with *ctypes* module ? Without any extra packeges . Only with fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should just use  [`pyperclip`](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/), which just solves the clipboard problem in a crossplatform way.

For Linux, though, it just tries to use the clipboard from GTK, Qt as it sees fit, or from  x11 using an external process - [(source code for pyperclip)](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/blob/master/src/pyperclip/__init__.py)

If you really want to get the values or set the clipboard in process and directly for x11, you can try to use Python-xlib bindings https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib - they do the ctypes part for you, and then [check this document which details how to access the clipboard properly](https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2017-04-02/0/POSTING-en.html).