# How to export data to csv/excel from clipboard with python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, csv, clipboard

I have being trying to export a table to a csv file. The table is copied to the clipboard and it is ready to be put into a csv (at least manually).

I have seen that you can read with pandas anything that you have in the clipboard and assign it to a dataframe, so I tried this code.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

However, I got this error:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 10 fields in line 5, saw 16. Error could possibly be due to 
quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

I have being looking for a solution or an alternative but failed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the pandas module a requrment here ? You could read clipboard like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-clipboard (at least on Windows) and write it with standard csv module or one of available modules for xlsx (eg. xlsxwriter)

Comment: It would be highly recommended. The thing is that when I store the data in the clipboard, if I paste it manually into the xlsx file it works amazingly well (even keeps the formats). However it is never that easy... :(
I have thought to move the data to a txt file but it would need a lot of parsing so I'm aiming for this approach

Comment: Does this error occur all the time or just when you have specific things on your clipboard?

Comment: And what is the source of data. I bet it would be better to retrieve data automatically from its origin instead of clipboard.