# Python - get selected Text in third party app without clipboard

Tags: python

I have a translation application for a niche language.
If the user selects/highlights text (typically in the browser) I want the translation func to get triggered. It manually checks and if the language is detected it translates.

I do have my onMouseUp Listener that triggers. **However I  don’t know how to get the selected text, how to put it into a variable (without triggering ctrl+c** and possibly overwriting the users clipboard)

Iam not sure what I am trying to do is possible.

Is it possible to get the users selected/highlighted text in an other app (browser), without triggering ctrl+c and clipboard?

Used pyperclip package however since it uses clipboard it overrides the users current clipboard text which might be important to the user.

Answer (score 0):

So it is not a problem for you to use the clipboard, provided you can keep the old clipboard -- right? So would it be possible for you to *save* the old clipboard first. Do whatever you want to do and then later *restore* the clipboard?

Some ideas when using Windows: [How do I read text from the clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-clipboard) From there specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38171680/20320247) could help gross-platform.

Comment: What if the user modifies the clipboard in between the time the dev saves the old clipboard and the time the dev restores it?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very bad approach which I have been using so far. It is even worse if the user has multi-clipboard enabled because it messes up the clipboard history, especially since some users trigger the function a few hundred times a day. That’s why I was looking for a non-clipboard approach, something like an api to the browser or win app but I didn’t find anything

Comment: Good points. So the aim is to have a drag-and-drop type of functionality without the actual physical drag and drop task.