# When running win32clipboard.OpenClipboard() i get "Access denied" error message

Tags: python, clipboard, pywin32

Its supposed to whire whatever is in my clipboard to a file and stop when pressing control + shift + p that part works but the getting clipboard doesnt.

Heres my code

```
import win32clipboard
import keyboard
filename = input("Filename: ")
file = open(filename, "a")
data = ""
while True:
   previousdata = data
   win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
   data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
   win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
   print(data)
   if data != previousdata:
       file.write(data+"\n")
   else:
       print("No change")
   if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl+shift+p"):
       break
print("Stopped")
import os
os.system("pause")
```

And here is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Juli\Desktop\python\clipboardcopy.py", line 8, in <module>
   win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenClipboard', 'Access denied.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like PyWin32 has an issue with the clipboard getting locked by other processes, resulting in an "Access is Denied" message.

Try calling the API directly using ctypes. As a bonus your code will also not rely on a 3rd party packages that's not included with the interpreter.

Here's an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-clipboard/23285159#23285159

Comment: Well now its not spitting out errors instead its only putting "<function get_clipboard_text at 0x0000023210863E20>" into the file. Oh wait nevermind fiqured it out while writing this. Was missing () nope not working now its just writing to my clipboard "Not Found"

Comment: Just simplyfied my other comment its not working and started writint "Not Found" into my clipboard

Comment: Here is the new code
https://pastebin.com/6Ni9Hevp